# Retrieve array of child elements in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to count/retrieve a specific DOM element from an array in Protractor. `openMenu` is a valid DOM element.

```
var openSelectbox = $('body > .ui-select-container');
var openMenu = openSelectbox.$('.ui-select-choices');
var choices = openMenu.all(by.css('.ui-select-choices-row'));
```

According to [the docs](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) I should now be able to call `choices.count()` for an int count of elements matched. Instead, it returns an [object with callback/closure keys](https://pste.me/#/a1Gwf). Not a promise, either.

`choices` should match three DOM elements. In the end, I need to use something like `choices.get(1).click();`.

Comment: How did you get you get openMenu? Can you paste that bit of code?

Comment: Updated. I stripped out a bunch of tests which don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to select your stuff differently:

```
var openSelectbox = element(by.css('body > .ui-select-container'));
var openMenu = openSelectbox.element(by.css('.ui-select-choices'));
var choices = openMenu.all(by.css('.ui-select-choices'));
```

I got this stuff from here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md#user-content-finding-sub-elements

Comment: My understanding is that `$` is an alias for `element(by.css`. Maybe that's not entirely accurate, but I *am* seeing the same result using this same method.

Comment: Try doing it all in one css call, see if that works. That'll at least eliminate the possiblity of your dom assumption being incorrect.

Comment: Something like this: `element(by.css('body > .ui-select-container .ui-select-choices .ui-select-choices'));`

Comment: Weird... now suddenly the promise form *is* working. I'm not sure what changed - it works both with this format and my original $ format.

Comment: Not sure why it suddenly works, but thanks for looking. `openChoices.count().then(function(count) { });`